# how to get second table and third table of same name in htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit with java. In my page I have many tables but 4 tables are with the same name and same attributes. I want to process through these 4 tables separately. How can I get second table and third table among these 4 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You have a way to pass for all objects within a page, just pass the element  to select in this case "table", to get all tables in one array x.

```
var x = getElementsByTagName("table");
var nTables = x.length
```

now its easy the first element of the array x is the first table and so on.

Conclusion: for objects there's no need to know names, ids... to reach every object on any page, just get all the elements that you need and star to instance variables and compare things.

Very best :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [getElementsByName()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getElementsByName%28java.lang.String%29), or [getElementsByXpath()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath%28java.lang.String%29). Both functions return a list of HtmlElements, but on XPath you can filter to get only the desided tables.

```
final WebClient web = new WebClient();
final Page page = web.getPage("...");
List<?> tables = page.getElementsByName("repetitive_table_name");
HtmlElement secondTable = (HtmlElement) tables.get(1);
HtmlElement thirdTable = (HtmlElement) tables.get(2);
```

or

```
final WebClient web = new WebClient();
final Page page = web.getPage("...");
// This will return like the getElementsByName
List<?> tables = page.getElementsByXpath("//table[@id='repetitive_table_name']");
HtmlElement secondTable = (HtmlElement) tables.get(1);
HtmlElement thirdTable = (HtmlElement) tables.get(2);
```